# ActiveRecord count vs MySQL count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a discrepancy between my counts generated directly with MySQL and ActiveRecord.  The query that shows in my server (Rails) logs is:

```
SELECT u.id, AVG(u.price) AS avg_price, COUNT(u.id) AS unit_count 
FROM `properties` 
INNER JOIN units u ON properties.id = u.property_id
```

The returned result is (1, 200, 1), which is not what I'm expecting. However, when I copy and paste the query into MySql directly I get (1, 200, 25), which is what I was expecting.  What is the reasoning for the different returned results when the query is exactly the same?  I'm currently using Rails 4 and MySql 5.6.33.

EDIT:

```
Property
  .select("u.id, AVG(u.price) AS avg_price, COUNT(u.id) AS unit_count")
  .joins("INNER JOIN units u ON properties.id = u.property_id")
```

Comment: can I see the activerecord query? to me it looks like somehow the count(u.id) got mixed with the id (1 instead of 25) but could be something else

Comment: @Joel_Blum - that is the activerecord query, i just formatted to make it more readable.  I copied directly from my server log and pasted it into mysql workbench and get different results.

Comment: I meant the actual ruby code in your controller/model thats creating the query

Comment: @Joel_Blum - Oh sorry, I have updated my question with the query i use for ActiveRecord

Comment: I'm not sure this query makes sense without you grouping the items somehow, otherwise what are you counting/calculating average of?

Comment: @Joel_Blum - I thought the same thing too since I was using an aggregate function that I need to use a group by, but surely enough the query seems to work in mysql workbench without it.